# update a json database

Tags: python, json

I wanted to create a sort of database in json with python, but I don't know how to delete existing "value"

```json
{
    { "object" : 
        { "object_id" : 012345678}} 

}
```

and if the user create a new object with the same object name, but a different object I'd value, it will update.

sorry for my bad explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the JSON library and trying to update data after you have added data with Python then you can use this

```json
data = # adding stuff to the json file using json library
with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```